# What does this range notation mean: 0:01 < x < 10:0

Tags: notation

I've got a homework problem which states "use a range of 0:01 < x < 10:0"

I'm thinking this would mean the range 0.00, 0.01, 0.02, ... 9.98, 9.99, 10.00

Has anyone seen this notation before that can tell me what this range would be?

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Could you please describe the context of the problem?

Comment: Sure, here's the problem: Each of the following equations can be represented as a straight line on an x-y plot by choosing the appropriate axis scales. Plot them both in rectangular coordinate format and then in an appropriate format to yield a straight line. Explain how the plot operation yields the straight line. Variable y has units of volts. Variable x has units of meters (use a range of 0:01 < x < 10:0). Note: This is easily done using a spreadsheet program where you can compare the use of different axis scales.

Comment: You might want to edit that into your question. That being said, I don't know why they're using ":"...

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what $0{:}01$ means, but if it means $0.01$ then what a range of $0{:}01<x<10{:}0$ means is that $x$ is greater than $0.01$ meters and less than $10$ meters. I suppose the $0$ is excluded so that you can take logarithms.

Comment: This answer should be right. If I google something like "use a range of 0:01 < x", I get one of results "and x(0) = _x(0) = 0:1, solve the VdP system for h = 0:01", whereas in the referenced book this string is "and x(0) = _x(0) = 0.1, solve the VdP system for h = 0.01". Maybe it's some weird and rare OCR problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the usual decimal symbol anywhere. Even in Europe they will use the comma instead (e.g. 0,05). This just means (0.01,10.00) not including the endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

I think all it means is, when you plot your points, use only values of $x$ between $.01$ and $10$. But I am confused as to why someone would write $0{:}01$ and $10{:}0$ instead of $0.01$ and $10.0$.